# how to drawing traveled way google map api v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer, google-maps-api-2

I want to draw the way, which i traveled on google map api v2, but i dont know how to do that.
I want to do just like that:
[image: This is app "My tracks"]

[image: This is app Sports tracker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to draw a travelled distance you need the list of "points" you walked through.

Assuming you have the List objects of the track you have just to draw a polyline:

```
// Add a thin red line 
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .addAll(YOUR_POINTS)
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

Then you have to add start end end marker if you need. Just do (example for start):

```
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(START_POSITION)
     .title("Start")
     .snippet("Start"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This site have all examples related to maps

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/